# Reading data from Angular Elements Web Component in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component, angular9, angular-elements

I'm building a few `WebComponent` that I'll be using across different libraries/frameworks, but mostly with plain vanilla `JavaScript`. I'm considering using [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) for this, and built a sample one following few documents.

It works fine, with all natural Angular goodies built in. But, what I'm struggling with is, **reading data out of the web component from plain `JavaScript`, something like `var result = myComponent.value`**.

- Note that this data I'm reading is not primitive, or a single value. It's like an object with many details from a complex `WebComponent`
- I'd want something like a `readonly property`
- Standard `Angular` documents for components always use `@Output()` with an `EventEmitter` for this purpose. But since I'll be using the component as `WebComponent` outside `Angular` world, I cannot (and don't want to) use that approach. Also, I do not want to notify on each change of the value, but just read the value when needed

If I'm writing a standard `WebComponent` in plain `JavaScript`, I can do this

```js
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.name = 'Guest';
        this.count = 0;
    }

    // more code...

    // THIS result PROPERTY IS USED TO READ DATA FROM THE WEB COMPONENT
    get result() {
        return { name: this.name, count: this.count }; // <<== to read data
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <style>
                styles....
            </style>
            <h1>MyComponent</h1>
            More HTML...
        `;
    }
}

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);

// Then I can use <my-component></my-component> in my application HTML
// And in the JavaScript code, I can read data from my-component as

const result = document.querySelector('my-component').result;
// which would be something like { name: 'Guest', count: 0 }
```

Is there a way to do this in `AngularElements` ?

Comment: Can you use plain JS ``Object.defineProperty``?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Could you explain a bit how `Object.defineProperty()` will help in the scenario?

Comment: From your NG code define a property with only a getter returning an object, behavior is then exactly the same as the ``result`` getter in your vanilla code above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have got 2 workarounds to deal with it for now! They are more like hacks as (1) they are not done the standard `Angular` way, and (2) might break in future with implementation changes within `Angular`. Below are the 2 ways I could achieve an `output property` for a `WebComponent` built with `Angular Elements`

(I'm using `"@angular/core": "~9.1.11"` & `"@angular/elements": "^9.1.11"`)

1. My colleague pointed out that `createCustomElement` only exposes inputs as properties. See code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2fc5ae561b2d2f3ec2b90cf580c41bf6f5b55fda/packages/elements/src/create-custom-element.ts#L220). SO the ***hack*** is, to mark a property as `Input()` then just read it from outside like a normal property! It's very non-intuitive and doesn't follow any standard semantics. And it's interesting that `Angular` does not complain if I have just a `getter` for a property decorated with `@Input()`
2. A better approach, as was pointed out by `Danny '365CSI' Engelman` in the comments, we can define a new property on the native HTML element, using `Object.defineProperty`

Note that, instead of option (1), a better approach could be to enhance/extend the logic in `Angular` to include other properties from the component class as the element properties, maybe with a new custom decorator like `@outputProperty`.

Sample code with implementation of both the above approaches

```js
// The component
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    // selector, templateUrl & styleUrls
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private element: ElementRef,
    ) {
        // THIS IS APPROACH 2 => we are defining a 'result2' property on the HTMLElement
        Object.defineProperty(this.element.nativeElement, 'result2', {
            get: () => { return { name: this.name, count: this.count }; },
            enumerable: true,
        });
    }

    public name = 'World';
    public count = 0;

    // More code for component functionalities and state management...

    // Just note that this does NOT work i.e. cannot read it from outside
    public get result0(): ElementMetadata {
        return { name: this.name, count: this.count };
    }
    public set result0(value) { console.log(`result value set to ${value}`); }

    // THIS IS APPROACH 1 => we are marking 'result1' with a getter, as @Input
    @Input()
    public get result1(): ElementMetadata {
        return { name: this.name, count: this.count };
    }
}

// The module (no changes made specifically for this)
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    ngDoBootstrap() {
        const custElement = createCustomElement(
            MyComponent,
            { injector: this.injector },
        );
        customElements.define('my-component', custElement);
    }
}
```